# i want to delete lines from the top of the text file (Except 7000 lines from the End)

Tags: c#

the below code deleting the particular line like: line no 12

**but exactly the need is keep the last 7000 lines and delete the remaining lines from the top of the txt.**

```
string line = null;
int line_number = 0;
int line_to_delete = 12;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input")) {
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output")) {
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        line_number++;

        if (line_number == line_to_delete)
            continue;

        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: so, what is your problem exactly? You already have a code that delete some line. Just fix it a little, so it will delete more then one line.

Comment: Implicitly you care about memory consumption? There are two solutions similar to the above. You can pass over the file twice counting the number of lines and dropping N-7000 before starting to write, or you can keep a 7000 line shift register, which requires only a single pass but uses 7000 * M memory where M is the number of characters per line on average. -_O_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines(fileName);

// if the file is less or equal than 7000, do nothing
if(linesToKeep.Count() > 7000) {
     linesToKeep = linesToKeep.Skip(linesToKeep.Count() - 7000);

    File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);

    File.Delete(fileName);
    File.Move(tempFile, fileName);
}
```

Of course the 7000 can be substituted by something else like a variable.

Comment: This looks like it would work, however it reads the entire file to memory. It appears they wish to stream over the file to keep memory consumption low.

Answer (score 0):

Two passes of the file for low memory footprint.

```
int lines_to_keep = 7_000;
string line = null;

int line_number = 0;
int lines_in_file = 0;

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input")) {
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        lines_in_file++;
    }
}

int lines_to_discard = lines_in_file - lines_to_keep 

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input")) {
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output")) {
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null && line_number < lines_to_discard) {
        line_number ++
    }
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        writer.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If this isn't for some big code base you can also use the bash tool `tail -7000`

Comment: Is `7_000` really valid code? Also, in c# we generally use `camelCase` and not `snake_case` for variables, but still valid though

Comment: Not sure about C#. I do mostly golang these days and underscores are permitted for readability. I believe C# introduced this in version 7